# Erro o Windows não pode encontrar 'svcutil.exe'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Entre os muitos projetos aqui na empresa, existe um que quando eu vou compilar dá o seguinte erro:

[image: svcuil.exe]

> O Windows não pode encontrar 'svcutil.exe'

O que faço para resolver esse erro?

Esta é a versão do meu Visual e do Framework:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
- Pastas em `Microsoft SDKs\Windows`:

  `v7.0A`, `v7.1A`, `v8.0`, `v8.0A`, `v8.1` e `v8.1A`

Só um dos projeto apresenta o erro, os demais rodam normalmente, o projeto que apresenta o erro esta usando a versão:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35667/discussion-on-question-by-pnet-erro-o-windows-nao-pode-encontrar-svcutil-exe)

Answer (score 2):

O que faltava era pegar o caminho completo do aplicativo, que no caso era este `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools` e colocar na variável de ambiente `PATH` após o `;`.

Para trocar vá até:

- Meu computador > Configurações avançadas > Variáveis de ambiente
- Procure a palavra `PATH` e de dois cliques com o mouse (rato)
- Edite o campo valor da variável e depois vá apertando em todos "Ok"
- As vezes é necessário fazer logoff ou reiniciar, mas nem sempre é preciso

Antes eu havia criado uma variável nova e coloquei lá. Não funcionou. Então, peguei o path completo e coloquei na variável `PATH`, que já existe no ambiente do windows. Com isso consegui fazer funcionar. Ou seja, o Windows encontrou o aplicativo.

Comment: Qual path você colocou na variável de ambiente?

Comment: No PATH do windows, na variável que leva esse nome.

Comment: PATH do windows eu entendi, se chama variavel de ambiente, o que não esta claro é que valor que você adicionou após o `;`.

Comment: Como eu disse, o valor é o path completo da pasta onde está o arquivo svcutil.exe. Foi isso que eu coloquei lá, que na mimnha máquina seria isso: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`

Comment: Então coloca isso na resposta, porque do jeito que esta escrito não deu a entender que era esse o caminho, por favor entenda como uma critica construtiva e que vai ajudar a sua resposta ser valorizada ;)

Comment: Eu editei e coloquei alguns exemplos, assim a sua resposta poderá ajudar usuários futuros que venham a enfrentar o mesmo tipo de problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o que tenho a dizer é muito obrigado. Ficou melhor mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a versão do SDK para .net 4.0 disponivel aqui:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

svcutil.exe que fica em v7.1/bin tem a versao 3.0...(não 4.0)

svcutil.exe que fica em v7.1/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools tem a versa 4.0...(4.0, voce deve usar esse!)